# De-serializing an object to class object

Tags: java, networking, serialization, udp

I'm working on a Token Ring network implementation, I'm trying to passing a token frame from the station to the ring using a `DatagramPacket`. I convert the frame object to a byte array using this:

```
public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    o.writeObject(obj);
    return b.toByteArray();
}
```

and then converting it back using this:

```
public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
    return o.readObject();
}
```

Each station is running two threads.

```
public void go() {

t.println("Sending to: " + main_host_address);
t.println("Station Address: " + station_address);
t.println("MAC Address: " + MAC_Address);


DatagramSocket socket;
InetSocketAddress saddr;

try {
        saddr= new InetSocketAddress("localhost", main_host_address);
        socket= new DatagramSocket(station_address); // Create a socket and a datagram from the buffer data

        (new Thread(new receivingThread(socket))).start();  // start threads for receiving and sending
        (new Thread(new sendingThread(socket, saddr, frame))).start();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}       
}
```

..and they all receive from one address - the ring.

Now in the `Ring` class, I'm trying to convert the byte array but it doesn't do anything, I'm running a while loop but it doesnt loop around once it tries to convert a byte array to a the `Frame` object.

```
 public void run() {
        byte [] buffer;
        DatagramPacket packet;
        //Receive the packet
        try{
            buffer = new byte[5];
            int i = 0;
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            int recievedData = 0;

            while(true){
                t.println("Recieving....");
                socket.receive(packet);

                Thread.sleep(2000);

                recievedData = packet.getData()[0];
                t.println("Reciever: " + recievedData);

                //here I'm trying a different way of getting the byte array
                //Before, I had; byte [] data = packet.getData(); 
                //but it didnt work so i was trying this longer way
                //and still the same result.
                List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();

                for(i = 0; i < packet.getData().length; i++){
                    t.print(packet.getData()[i] + " ");
                    list.add(packet.getData()[i]);
                }

                Byte [] d = list.toArray(new Byte[list.size()]);
                byte[] data = new byte[d.length];

                int j=0;
                for(Byte b: d){
                    data[j++] = b.byteValue();
                }
                frame = (Frame) deserialize(data); //I think the problem is here
                t.println("From frame: " + frame.SD[0]);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){  

        }
    }
```

How can I fix this please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize `(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength()).`

In other words adjust your API so that these extra offset and length parameters are passed to your deserialize() method, and are used when constructing your `ByteArrayInputStream.`